# Commas in WPF Pack URIs

Tags: c#, wpf

[WPF Pack URIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx) use three consecutive commas, for example:

```
pack://application:,,,/myFolder/myPic.bmp
```

Is the `,,,` part supposed to mean anything? Is it just a delimiter? Can anything go between the commas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Background

A URI [is composed of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax) a **scheme**, **authority**, and **path**<sup>1</sup>.
For example, take the `http` URL of this web page:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256056/commas-in-wpf-pack-uris

scheme    = https://
authority = stackoverflow.com
path      = /questions/16256056/commas-in-wpf-pack-uris
```

## `pack` URIs

The same applies to your `pack` URI:

```
pack://application:,,,/myFolder/myPic.bmp

scheme    = pack://
authority = application:,,,
path      = /myFolder/myPic.bmp
```

What's unusual here, is that the **authority** part consists of an encoded representation of **another URI**. That other URI looks like this:

```
application:///

scheme    = application://
authority = 
path      = /
```

It refers to a "package" – specifically, to the package of resource files of the current application. From the [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#the-pack-uri-scheme) you already linked:

> WPF supports two authorities: application:/// and siteoforigin:///. The application:/// authority identifies application data files that are known at compile time, including resource and content files. The siteoforigin:/// authority identifies site of origin files.

In order to be used as the **authority** component of the `pack` URI, it needs to be encoded so that its slashes aren't misinterpreted as belonging to the **path** component of the `pack` URI.
The way they chose to encode it, is by replacing slashes with commas.
From the same documentation page:

> Note
>   The authority component of a pack URI is an embedded URI that points to a package and must conform to RFC 2396. Additionally, the "/" character must be replaced with the "," character, and reserved characters such as "%" and "?" must be escaped. See the OPC for details.

---

<sup>1) Plus potentially a query and fragment, but those aren't relevant here.</sup>

Comment: This is the epitome of how to over-engineer and over-complicate something that should actually be straightforward, i.e. "I want to locate an embedded or local resource file".  Just another reason why WPF is such a painfully arcane framework.    The doc page doesn't seem to even explain the need for the embedded URL in the first place.  Can we use other embedded authorities, why would we need to do that?  Just an awful design choice overall actually, but it is Microsoft so no surprise.

Comment: In URI application:///, why the authority part left as empty, what does that mean? I wonder.

Answer (score 8):

The answer is on the page you linked to,

> - Authority: `application:///`

and

> ... Additionally, the "/" character must be replaced with the "," character, and reserved characters such as "%" and "?" must be escaped. See the OPC for details

So

> Is the `,,,` part supposed to mean anything?

It's a substitute for `///`

> Can anything go between the commas?

<strike>No.</strike>

Correction:  The OPC (Open Packaging) link leads to [ECMA-376](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm) and that contains examples like
`pack://http%3c,,www.openxmlformats.org,my.container/a/b/foo.xml`

but afaik that does not apply to WPF.

Comment: I just visited the linked page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069.aspx and it does NOT mention anything about replacing the '///' with commas.  It shows "application:///" and then immediately afterwards gives examples that show the slashes replaced with commas, but it doesn't even mention the replacement or explain why they are replaced.  To look at it is confusing and the entire syntax is a monstrosity.  I don't know how they expect anyone to use this.

Comment: It is solving a much larger problem and I suppose the expectation was for much more tooling for WPF. That just never happened.

Comment: Perhaps your answer would be more informative if you would mention (should you know) why there is apparently a need (is there?) to replace /// with ,,, I have to admit, recently being confronted with this myself, that it all seems much like a bunch of magical incantations rather than anything else.

Comment: @Kris: I know it's late, but I added a more in-depth answer.