# Commas in path - .NET

Tags: windows, url, path, filesystems, uri

I am working on some code that has paths that look like this:

```
"pack://application:,,,/FOO.Bar.Baz;component/Gorp/bazzle.xaml"
```

What do the 3 commas mean, and what is this path referencing?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256056/commas-in-wpf-pack-uris

Answer (score 1):

Typically they are placeholders for parameters that were not supplied.  It usually means ... "use the default values" for those parameters.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean... If you are talking about the foo, bar, baz stuff, I added that to make the question more generic. ;)

Comment: The method or module that is processing the path is most likely splitting the path into separate components.  Each component represents a "parameter value".  Commas are often used to delimit these parameter values/components.  The first parameter value would be pack://application:.  The second parameter value was omitted.  The third parameter value was also omitted.  The fourth parameter value is the extra text you supplied "/FOO.Bar.Baz;component/Gorp/bazzle.xaml".  The processing method/module will need to supply default values for those two omitted parameters (2 and 3).